# If gaps in data find most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, outer-join

I'm joining on 2 tables with an outer join.

```
SELECT T2.ID
FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN 
  TABLE2 as T2
  ON t1.date = t.date;
```

This can return data such as the following:

```
TABLE1.DATE =  03/15  03/16   03/17     03/18    03/19   03/30
TABLE2.DATE=   NULL   03/16   03/17     NULL     NULL    03/20
```

So when the dates in TABLE 2 are NULL I need to grab the most recent NON NULL date and then find the ID from Table 2 for that date.

I.E. on 3/15 the date will be NULL but on 03/16 I need to set the ID based upon data for 03/16 and populate for both 03/15 and 03/16.

For 03/18 and 03/19 the most recent date needs to be set to 03/17 and then the ID based upon 03/17 applied to 03/18 and 03/19.

What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I'm rather confused as to how a query that selects one `id` can return rows with 6 or 7 columns, most of which are dates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: it looks like OP is showing a pivoted version of their dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery, or `outer apply` if you want more than one column from the other table:

```
select t1.date t1_date, t2.date t2_date, t2.id t2_id
from table1 t1
outer apply (
    select top (1) t2.*
    from table2 t2
    where t2.date <= t1.date
    order by t2.date desc
) t2
```